# what is this dynamic for loop in java

Tags: java, for-loop

I've seen a different approach of using the FOR loop like this after create a "List" object type.

```
List<Focus> focuses = new ArrayList<Focus>();
String my_string = "";
for (Focus obj1 : list_obj_x) {
    my_string += obj1;
}
```

I don't understand how this FOR loop works in this situation.

Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't understand *if* it worked... What is `list_obj_x`, apart from being a variable name that violates naming conventions?

Comment: The code won't work. Because I would like to know how the FOR loop works or the name of this FOR loop.

Comment: A lot of things don't work. You can't append an instance of `Focus` to a string, for example. (Should be `my_string += obj1.toString()` or something like that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The enhanced for loop can be used with any object that implements `Iterable<X>` and with arrays. It is equivalent to using a for loop with an iterator (in case of an iterable):

```
// with Iterables:

Iterable<String> iterableStrings = getListOfStrings();

// standard for loop
for (Iterator<String> it = iterableStrings.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
   String s = it.next();
   System.out.println(s);
}

// enhanced for loop
for (String s : iterableStrings) {
   System.out.println(s);
}

// with arrays:

String[] stringArray = getStringArray();

// standard for loop
for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
   String s = stringArray[i];
   System.out.println(s);
}

// enhanced for loop
for (String s : stringArray) {
   System.out.println(s);
}
```

It's usage is *not* limited to "indexed collections" like lists and arrays.

**Reference**

[JLS 14.14.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2)

Answer (score 3):

It's called [**enhanced for-loop/For-Each construct**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html). introduced in java 1.5. it was introduced primarly to iterate over collections and arrays.

This:

```
List<Focus> focuses = new ArrayList<Focus>();
String my_string = "";
for (Focus obj1 : list_obj_x) {
    my_string += obj1;
}
```

is same as

```
List<Focus> focuses = new ArrayList<Focus>();
String my_string = "";
for (int i=0; i<focuses.size(); i++) {
    my_string += focuses.get(i);
}
```

Note that however, you can only use for-each loop for those objects which implement [**Iterable interface**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html).

> Implementing this interface allows an object to be the target of the
>   "foreach" statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (Focus obj1 : list_obj_x) {
    my_string += obj1;
}
```

When you see the colon (:) read it as “in.” The loop above reads as “for each Focus obj1  in list_obj_x.” As you can see, the for-each construct combines beautifully with generics. It preserves all of the type safety, while removing the remaining clutter. Because you don't have to declare the iterator, you don't have to provide a generic declaration for it. (The compiler does this for you behind your back, but you need not concern yourself with it.)

And equivalent to above for each loop is:

```
for (int i =0 ; i< list_obj_x.size(); i++) {
    my_string += list_obj_x.get(i);
}
```